# 'fj' ligatures are not correctly mapped with 'glyphtounicode' using Alegreya font

Tags: fonts, unicode, ligatures, copy-paste

Inputting `glyphtounicode` when compiling with `pdflatex` makes sure that various ligatures in the output are copy- and searchable. With the [`Alegreya`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alegreya) package, however, the ligatures for `fj` and `ffj` aren't rendered correctly. Is there a way to work around it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\input glyphtounicode
    \pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
fb ffb ff fh ffh fi ffi fj ffj fk ffk fl ffl ft fft
\end{document}
```

Copy-and-paste from `.pdf`:

`fb ffb ff fh ffh fi ffi  f fk ffk fl ffl ft fft`

Comment: @barbarabeeton `glyphtounicode` should be in tex live 2015, because I haven't installed or downloaded anything manually. (I have an idea about how `Alegreya` is mapping those non-unicode ligatures, but I'm on my way out now, so I'll come back to that. But in short, I believe the `f` in inputs like `fb`, `fk`, etc. is mapped to a different `f` glyph, which then `glyphtounicode` is able to map back onto an `f`. So, the output `fk` here is not a single ligature, it's just the combination of a different `f` + `k`. I guess `fj` _is_ a real ligature, and `glyphtounicode`can't deal with it.

Comment: since unicode does not assign a code to the `fj` ligatures (nor to `fb`, `fh`, `fk` or `ft` ligatures), it's not clear to me how `Alegreya` is making these connections.  they're not defined in `glyphtounicode`.  under the circumstances, this seems to be something that should be reported to the maintainers of `Alegreya`.

Comment: `fj` *should* be a real ligature!  (and norwegians should complain otherwise, as should slartibartfast.) (and i have since found `glyphtounicode` in tex live 2015, although i'm unable to locate it directly on ctan.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sure, what I mean is that `fb`, `fk` and `ft` aren't "real" ligatures in the `Alegreya` font in the sense that they are composed of a single glyph - they just look like ligatures because the font provides context sensitive variants of `f`. Whereas it seems like `fj` is a single glyph in the font, and that's why `glyphtounicode` can't do anything about it (since the ligature is not included in Unicode). (And yes, as a Norwegian I am very unhappy about fonts without a `fj` ligature `:)`)

Comment: actually, `glyphtounicode` doesn't even contain anything i could recognize as an `fi` of `ff` ligature, so they are recognized in some other way which i can only speculate about.  you say that they "aren't rendered correctly", but it's implied that they *do* appear correct in the output, and the problem is with cutting and pasting that result back to input form.  if you could add the output view of your example, that would be more clear.  (there must be some way of determining the "unicode" or `utf8` value of these glyphs; i suspect this one is in the private use area.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you compile with pdflatex you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\pdfglyphtounicode{fj}{0066 006A}% f j

\begin{document}
fb ffb ff fh ffh fi ffi fj ffj fk ffk fl ffl ft fft
\end{document}
```